How to prevent repeating data in JasperSoft TextField when overflow happens
I'm using JasperSoft Studio 6.17.0.
I need to make a form that have a table made of TextField on it, and that table takes more than one page to be printed. So, some rows of that table (i.e. TextFiedls) have to overflow from one page to another. I could make that to work, but now I have another problem: the text values in columns that is too short for overflow following the tallest object in a band just repeating on the next page. I need to prevent this.
There was exactly same question here, but the solution was for the version from ten years ago, and the current version had its functions changed.
I've tried different combinations of options like Print Repeated Values, Detail Overflows, consume.space.on.overflow.
If I disable Detail Overflows - the text stops getting printed on the next page, but the border stops also (and I need to keep the border).
If I disable Detail Overflows and put TextField in borded Frame, I get only the left border on the next page for some, the upper border disappears.
For better explanation of my problem, I even attach the picture from that question.
enter image description here
I could not get that result and hope you will help me.

Found the answer by myself.

Place each individual table row in a Frame object. One frame - several TextFields forming a line.
Make settings for the frame:
a. Appearance - Position Type: Float
b. Appearance - Stretch Type: Relative to Tallest
c. Appearance - Detail Overflow: false
d. Appearance - Border Split Type: Draw Borders
e. Borders - Set a full circular border
For each text field, make the following settings:
a. Appearance - Position Type: Float
b. Appearance - Stretch Type: Relative to Tallest
c. Appearance - Detail Overflow: false
d. Text Field - Text Adjust: StretchHeight
For each frame, create its own Detail block and place the frame there.
For each item, make the following settings:
a. Appearance - Split Type: Immediate
Reduce the vertical size of the Text Field, Frame and Detail elements to a minimum - 20 pixels is enough.

